# Image uploading from computer not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a particular code and it works fine on Google chrome but not on IE9. 
i have a div and i drag an image from computer to the div and it loads on Google Chrome but not with IE9. Please help..!

```
<div id="holder" ></div> 
    <p id="status">
        Please Drag your image from computer and paste it on the div to view it.
    </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var holder = document.getElementById('holder'), 
state = document.getElementById('status'); 

if (typeof window.FileReader === 'undefined') { 
    state.className = 'fail'; 
} else { 
   state.className = 'success'; 
   state.innerHTML = 'Please Drag your image from computer and paste it on the div to view it.'; 
} 

holder.ondragover = function () { 
    this.className = 'hover'; 
    return false; 
}; 

holder.ondragend = function () { 
    this.className = ''; 
    return false; 
}; 

holder.ondrop = function (e) { 
    this.className = ''; 
    e.preventDefault();    
    var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0], 
    reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.onload = function (event) { 
        alert(event); 
        console.log(event.target); 
        holder.style.background = 'url(' + event.target.result + ') no-repeat center'; 
    }; 

    console.log(file); 
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    return false; 
};
```

What could be the problem??

Comment: Share your code at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 [File](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) API is not supported by IE9 browser

**UPD:** and HTML5 [Drag and Drop](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dnd.html#dnd) API support in IE9 is only partial, the part you are trying (`dataTransfer.files`) is not supported. [Here](http://caniuse.com/#search=drop) you can see what browsers support drag and drop HTML5 API

Comment: Thank a lot bro for ya help. I have one more question. I'm including jquery plugins for drag and drop and im trying to use fancybox plugin as well. So when i include fancybox plugin, d drag and drop function stops working. Do you know what could be the problem? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: there's no way to tell what's wrong without your code and/or error message.

Comment: ok. I m using these 3 plugins.
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

when i use the first and the second. dragging and resizing wrks fine. and when i include the third one. it stops. i dun wanta know the complete solution. Just want to know if theres possibility that d plugins do stop wrkin?

Comment: you use 2 different versions of jQuery, pick one. You don't need two of them, they may conflict with each other.

Comment: i m sorry maksim but i m a noobie in this. Could u tel me how do you differentiate among the plugins?

Comment: Your first external javascript is older version of jQuery library (1.3.2), second is jQuery UI library, you don't need it in your example and third one is newer version of jQuery (1.4). Remove your first script (older jQuery) and it may solve your issues. Feel free to accept the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it is not supported until IE10 version 2010.3
Check which version you're using at the moment

Comment: what is IE9 version 2010.3? I think you meant IE10.

Comment: yup, sorry for typo. editted. IE9 does not support it at all and it will be supported since IE10 2010.3. However, it seems it used to be supported in previous IE versions

Comment: I recently downloaded IE9. but i cudnt find IE10. is it launched?

Comment: Yes, preview and RTM versions are released. Note, you need to use Win7 or later OS (only Win8 for RTM)

Comment: Any particular link from where i can download this? Thanks in advance

Comment: RTM version comes together with Win8. One of developer previews can be downloaded from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2587683